# jQuery alternative to bind('load') for use with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

So the `.load()` method has been deprecated in jQuery. `load()` is a shortcut for `bind('load', function).

From http://api.jquery.com/load-event/:

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser It doesn't
>   fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>   before It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire
>   for images that already live in the browser's cache`

How does one perform a function on image load consistently? My Current code looks like so:

```
$(newImage).bind('load', function() {
    createSlices(slide); 
});
```

However after reading the docs (although I haven't noticed any problems) I am worried it may not fire for some users.

Comment: In my experience the native `onload` function is more reliable for this use than jQuery's `load()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin man: called `waitforimages` plugin: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages  (*scroll down the link you will see various advanced use*) - *demo* http://jsfiddle.net/FZ7Xy/

Hope it fits the need `:)`

**Code**

```
$('selector').waitForImages(function() {
    // All descendant images have loaded, now slide up.
    $(this).slideUp();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = new Image();  
img.onload = function() {

} 

img.src=  src-image
```

the above code works on all browsers and even without jquery.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for formatting.

Comment: This code is still subject to the same potential issues that the jQuery documentation outlines. The question is how to solve those issues, not how to preload an image.

Comment: native `onload` works on all browsers including IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to worry, IE7/8 in particular will sometimes fail to fire the *load* event if the image is cached.

One technique is to immediately check if the image is complete after binding the load event:

```
$(newImage).bind('load error', function() {
    createSlices(slide); 
});

// check if the image is immediately complete (cached)
if (newImage.complete || typeof newImage.complete === 'undefined') {
    createSlices(slide);
}
```

I've tested with success in:

- IE 7/8/9/10
- FF4+
- Chrome (latest)
- Safari 5+

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library that handles exactly this: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

I've used it in production and it works wonderfully. Extremely reliable, not a single complaint.